# Drupal 6 module development

Tags: drupal

Hi
I am going to develop Drupal 6 module, could someone please advise some reference about how to develop Drupal 6 module to me.

Thanks you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A similar Stack Overflow question, [Good drupal books/resources for programmers/developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201262/good-drupal-books-resources-for-programmers-developers), contains a lot of useful responses. Personally, if I could have only one resource, I'd want the [Pro Drupal Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430209895) book.

Beyond that, check out the [Examples for Developers](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) project and/or read the code of the [modules that ship with Drupal core](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/modules?h=6.x), for examples of how to do the basics. Those modules get lots of review and are good examples of the [Drupal coding standards](http://drupal.org/coding-standards).

Answer (score 1):

http://drupal.org/developing/modules This has plenty of links to satisfy your curiosity.

Comment: Also books recommend as more logical to understand this. I recommend Vandyk Pro Drupal development if you want to be professional drupal developer...

Comment: How about Learning Drupal 6 Module Development by Packtpub? Which book or the official website is easy to learning?

Comment: Pro Drupal Development is a superior book to Learning Drupal 6 Module Development (I have them both).

Answer (score 0):

[Lullabot](http://www.lullabot.com) has a very long video specifically on module development.

While a book (go for Pro Drupal Development!) is often easier for reference and can adjust to your speed, I've found that videos really augment the learning experience. It's easier to remember things (that's what voice does), and you follow the process of the developer/lecturer, which can be very beneficial in it's own right.

Answer (score 0):

if you know write php already and you want to know basic step for the create a module from Drupal you can reffer the link
http://drupallearn.blogspot.com/2011/10/create-custom-modules-on-drupal-create.html
you have to write your own code in module file.
hope this will be help.

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.